# How to solve InvocationTargetException in Gluon Mobile? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

I trying to create an IoT tool with Gluon JavaFX for mobile. When I try to login onto the mobile. I get this error.

```
10-18 00:11:30.213  2551  2589 W System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
10-18 00:11:30.213  2551  2589 W System.err: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
10-18 00:11:30.213  2551  2589 W System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime: Process: se.danielmartensson, PID: 2551
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
10-18 00:11:30.283  2551  2589 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.
10-18 00:11:30.283  2780  3298 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity se.danielmartensson/javafxports.android.FXActivity
```

This happens when I call this method

```
   /**
     * Connect the server or disconnect
     * 
     * @param event
     */
    @FXML
    void connectServer(ActionEvent event) {
```

From this [source](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/JLogger/blob/master/JLogger/JLoggerApp/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/ConnectServerPresenter.java)

I trying first API level 19, then I try use API level 23. Still same error. I'm using Apache Client for Android API 19 level. Do you know how to solve this? I cannot see where in my code the error is, or where the errors are to be precise.

The error appear on line 367, because if this is null, then I get a pop-up box that says "Cannot connect".

```
SimpleMessageStatus simpleMessageStatus =  new SimpleMessageStatus().getJsonMessage(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

But if it's not null, if I have connection, then I get an error. So after that line, I don't know exactly what's cause the error.

Comment: For starters, I'd use `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` whenever you have an error, that will let you see the full stack trace with `adb logcat`. Then add some printouts, to show some of the values you are getting, possible nulls, ...

Comment: @JoséPereda Ok! I will do that. Give you a reply in few minutes.

Comment: @JoséPereda Still the same. I did not find the root case that cause the error. Perhaps it is the Apache Client package? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/android.html

Comment: Apply my previous comment, divide your code (it is too big), print out values, print all possible exceptions. Move all Http code to a Service class let the FXML load first, see that it works, then inject the service, and go step by step...

Comment: @JoséPereda I found the cause of the error now `return httpclient.execute(http);` at https://github.com/DanielMartensson/JLogger/blob/d8f6bf9d3b6e0ab8daddc312be27e48343a0593c/JLogger/JLoggerApp/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/ConnectServerPresenter.java#L475 What do you recommend to do now if I know what line causing the trouble for me? Change library?

Comment: @JoséPereda Or do you think `Platform.runLater(() -> {code});` will help me here?

Comment: @JoséPereda This is exactly what I got after i run `httpclient.execute(http);` --> `AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread`

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes! I changed library from `org.apache.httpcomponents.client5` to `cz.msebera.android` and now my application works perfect.